# Autenticação e autorização em WebSockets

Tags: javascript, java, html5, websocket

Boa tarde, fui incumbido de construir uma aplicação Java que se comunica com um aplicativo para dispositivos móveis desenvolvido com tecnologias híbridas (HTML5, CSS3 e JavaScript), ao pesquisar no mercado a tecnologia que daria maior suporte as minha necessidades cheguei a conclusão que teria de utilizar WebSockets, no entanto nunca trabalhei com o mesmo, gostaria de saber se alguém teria algum exemplo de como utilizar Autorização e Autenticação tendo por tecnologia de comunicação WebSckets.

Comment: Só um toque para você levar em consideração: eu já considerei usar websockets para um aplicativo mobile sendo que na verdade o que eu realmente precisava era de _push notifications_ (GCM). Uma conexão websocket mantida aberta por muito tempo pode aumentar bastante o consumo de bateria do aparelho, às vezes até com um baixo volume de dados trafegados.

Comment: Teria algum tutorial ou material que me indica para consultar ?

Comment: Pesquise por _Google Cloud Messaging_. O material oficial do Google é em inglês mas você irá encontrar tutoriais sobre o assunto em português também. Para _push notifications_ que funcionem em diversas plataformas, pesquise sobre _mobile push notification providers_ como parse.com, Amazon SNS e outros.

Comment: Uma pergunta: O que tem `Java` haver com a questão? O servidor é usa Java?